# Facebook Retargeting Pixel code for React Native

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, react-native, facebook-events, facebook-pixel

Hi I am try to add facebook retargeting pixel for my react native app, and I am hoping that the community can help me clarify something. First, to track an event `PageView` or `ViewContent` of a product, I add the following script to the product page.

```
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {

        content_name: 'Truyện Cổ Grimm (Bìa Cứng)',
        content_category: 'Truyện đọc',
        content_ids: ['8935212329736'],
        content_type: 'product',
        value: 153750,
        currency: 'VND'

});
</script>
```

I wonder how can I achieve the same with React Native. I saw the Facebook have FB SDK for react native (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native), and I want to ask, is this SDK what I can achieve similar to what I have for a web above. That if I view a product, do I just do this?

```
AppEventsLogger.logEvent('ViewContent');
```

If so, however can I specify other parameters, maybe like this?

```
AppEventsLogger.logEvent('ViewContent', {

    content_name: 'Truyện Cổ Grimm (Bìa Cứng)',
    content_category: 'Truyện đọc',
    content_ids: ['8935212329736'],
    content_type: 'product',
    value: 153750,
    currency: 'VND'
});
```

Anyone with success experience with this, please help me out. Thank you very much

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You were correct to guess the event to be used with `react-native-fbsdk`. If you'll look into the source of this SDK [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/master/js/FBAppEventsLogger.js#L49) you'll see you can use `logEvent` method in various ways.

The method you guessed:

```
AppEventsLogger.logEvent('ViewContent', {
    content_name: 'Truyện Cổ Grimm (Bìa Cứng)',
    content_category: 'Truyện đọc',
    content_ids: ['8935212329736'],
    content_type: 'product',
    value: 153750,
    currency: 'VND'
});
```

Will log event on FB Analytics and then you can customize your reports on the basis of these params. During my experience with it, I faced one issue that it doesn't support arrays. So the above code will be changed as below:

```
AppEventsLogger.logEvent('ViewContent', {
    content_name: 'Truyện Cổ Grimm (Bìa Cứng)',
    content_category: 'Truyện đọc',
    content_ids: '8935212329736',
    content_type: 'product',
    value: 153750,
    currency: 'VND'
});
```

With this you should be good to go. I hope this solved your query.

**Note:**

Arrays are not supported by React Native Bridge right now. You can check [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/28b66be7b0383ac67f42ab8ff660f1048d9f5b98/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/Arguments.java#L184) for the place where arrays are not supported.

### Update September 2021

Facebook have now retired their official support of `react-native-fbsdk` but there is a [strong community fork](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next/) which is actively maintained.

Comment: maybe not as an array of as a json String. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/app-event-api/v2.8.

Comment: fb_content_id: If you have multiple content IDs, you should provided these in an escaped JSON array, for example: "[\"1234\",\"5678\"]"

Comment: @ThangPham wow this is an amazing find! I shall include this in the answer.